# Prestashop "PayPal transaction succeeded but no order created in prestashop issue"

Tags: paypal, prestashop

This is regards **payment taking through paypal but no order placed/created in Prestashop.**

From **admin logs
i can see the below log**

```
PaymentModule::validateOrder - Order cannot be created
```

I have checked this it came from
**/website/override/classes/PaymentModule.php**

Its because there was some issue while creating order

```
$result = $order->add();
```

That results into `PaymentModule::validateOrder - Order cannot be created` log.

**How do i find out which/what thing created issue that leads to order not created ?**

**How do i find out cause of the issue ?**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using Prestashop 1.7+, did you enable the Debug mode for additional error messaging?

Alternatively you could try with Xdebug in your code editor.

Or, find what module overrides the PaymentModule class, disable that module and see if the issue still appears.

If its the module's fault contact its developer or try to debug it.

Another quick test is to disable all overrides from the PS admin and check if it solves it (some third party module using this override system won't work but it is just to check).

Note: the Prestashop disavow using overrides in PS 1.7+, modules should be used instead.